# The resource "SearchBoxStyle" could not be resolved

Tags: silverlight

I am recieving following error in VS 2010.

I have two Silverlight projects. one project only contains `styles` and other project is my application. I have referenced styles project in my application and user static resources from that project in my whole application, but I keep recieving this error in VS though everything works fine when I compile and run the application.

> The resource "SearchBoxStyle" could not be resolved

Comment: Get the error where? In the designer? Do you get the same error in Blend?

Comment: yes, I get error in designer. no, I don't get this error in Blend.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I stumped on this one today and I am also looking for a solution.

It seems to be a missing feature of Visual Studio - VS XAML designer just cannot find static resources outside of the current XAML file.
It seems, Expression Blend is smarter and offers a workaround for such cases.

Here is a similar thread which suggests using Blend:
[The resource could not be resolved (VS 2010 RC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390924/wpf-staticresource-the-resource-could-not-be-resolved-vs-2010-rc)

And here is what Microsoft says about this issue:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546934(VS.90).aspx#ResourcesatDesignTime

And for me the solution was to put a / in the path of my resource and set the xaml file to compile as a resource. So my App.xaml looks like this:

```
  <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="/Resources/ControlStyles.xaml" />   
             </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <!-- Dummy Style for WPF 4 bug fix, anything you won't use goes -->
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type WebBrowser}" />
        </ResourceDictionary>
  </Application.Resources>
```

It failed to load at design time when I did not use the first slash in the path, but now it works fine at design time in other XAML pages.