# wpf resource is not found but still applied

Tags: wpf, resources

I'm having several projects in my solution which contain their own resources.
I make sure they are defined in main `App.xaml`:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
           <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MainMenu;component/Resources/Resources.xaml" />
           <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Main;component/Resources/Resources.xaml" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

the content in each `Resources.xaml` is applied.
but in the designer when I'm using them they appear with error:

```
<TextBlock
    Style="{StaticResource MainWindowTitleStyle}" />
```

The resource "MainWindowTitleStyle" could not be resolved.

how can I avoid these errors ?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390924/the-resource-could-not-be-resolved-vs-2010-rc

Comment: the post you past is for VS2010.
as i know the designer of 2012 should handle that

Comment: Sorry then, you never stated in your post what VS you are using ... :)

Answer (score 1):

There are stil some problems in the VS 2012 Designer, and this is one of them.

You can change your `StaticResource` references to `DynamicResource` and this should prevent the designer from throwing these design-time-only exceptions.

Comment: Though this may have negative performance implications for your application. StaticResources are shared. A good work around but, at no fault of @Stewbob, not a good solution.

Comment: @xr280xr, I couldn't agree more.  I'm currently having to do this on a couple of applications so that the designer will actually render the window, and the seriously increased build time is about driving me nuts. :)