# wpf resource is applied with error

Tags: wpf, resources

i'm having several projects in my solution which contain their own resources.
i make sure they are defined in main App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MainMenu;component/Resources/Resources.xaml" />
            <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/Main;component/Resources/Resources.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

the content in each Resources.xaml is applied.
but in the designer when i'm using them they appear with error:

```
<TextBlock
    Style="{StaticResource MainWindowTitleStyle}"
    />
```

The resource "MainWindowTitleStyle" could not be resolved.

how can i avoid these errors ?

Comment: Have you tried making a shortcut to the Resource file in the project you're using it?

Comment: Why did you post [same question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852835/wpf-resource-is-not-found-but-still-applied) twice?

Comment: sorry... it showed error on the first one... this one can be deleted.

Comment: HichemCSharp: sure, otherwise it won't work at all...

Comment: @kaycee Close the designer window, right click on the project and click "Rebuild".