# WPF - styling RadioButton as ToggleButton works, but shows error in VS

Tags: wpf, xaml

Working to create a top level menu in WPF, I used the trick of styling a RadioButton as a ToggleButton in order to get the "only one selected" effect. Like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModels}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <RadioButton  Content="{Binding Key.Name}" GroupName="MenuButtonGroup"
                      Style="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" >
        </RadioButton>
    </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

It works beautifully, and does just what I expect. But Visual Studio registers it as an error.

The Style property is underlined in blue and the description given is The resource "{x:Type ToggleButton}" could not be resolved.

It all looks above board but having this sat on my error list in Visual Stuido is hugely irritating. Any idea how to resolve it?

EDIT: Just found this question -

[The resource could not be resolved (VS 2010 RC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390924/the-resource-could-not-be-resolved-vs-2010-rc)

Which suggests it's a VS error. Anyone confirm this, or know of a fix? Wherever the problem is, it's still really annoying!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could move the style to a Resources collection e.g.

```
<Window.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="MyStyle" TargetType="{x:Type RadioButton}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ToggleButton}}" />
</Window.Resources>
```

and then reference that style:

```
<RadioButton  Content="{Binding Key.Name}" GroupName="MenuButtonGroup"
                         Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" />
```

Comment: Neat, thanks. Never occurred to try something that straightforward!